# Calculate the volume of the solid rotating

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the volume of the solid obtained by rotating around the $ y $ axis of the set. $A= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x, x^2 \leq y \leq 4 \right\}$

I think you do squared integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That set is symmetric about the y-axis so you only need to look at x> 0.  for any given y, between 0 and 4, x runs from 0 to $\sqrt{y}$.  Rotating around the y-axis we have a disk of radius $\sqrt{y}$ so area $\pi x^2= \pi y$ and, taking the thickness to be dy, volume $\pi y dy$.  The volume of the entire figure is $\pi \int_0^4 ydy$.